# Add a polygon to PostGis from Google Maps

Tags: postgis, google-maps

i have some experience with Google maps api, I have an app and currently calculate nearest points to locations via distance functions (great circle) and having a lot of waypoints on MySQL.

I want to start with PostGis in order to do this a better way or have been able to give a user the ability to build a polygon in GMAPS (point and click on map, saving each lat,lon, connecting the last with the first.

I've just downloaded postgresplus to start with this but don't have reference to this:
1. create a table of polygons
2. insert via php each polygon to PostGis
3. be able to query the polygon to see if a point is inside or outside a polygon

I know all this is very efficent with PostGis but have 0 experience with it.

does someone knows a link or site to learn all this basics of postgis

thanks

NA

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest starting [here](http://sites.google.com/site/mapperzmapdemo/). I believe the author of that tutorial to be a member of this very site, and suspect you'll hear from him as well. Good luck, and equally importantly - have fun with it.

Comment: Yes I did the demo. Any questions can be answered here.

Comment: Thanks Mapperz, still starting with PostGis Installation, got PostGresPlus package for Mac and will start with this so I can go this way. Thanks Herb and Mapperz